# Why axios gets incorrect port number

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm doing a react project and getting data from a server. I'm using axios for that.

```
    axios
      .post(baseURL, bodyParameters, config)
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log(response.data);
        if (response.status === 201) {
          alert("Added successfully");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(error);
        alert("An unexpected error occured! please check the values and try again");
      });
```

the url that I'm using is

```
  const baseURL = "/api/Etaperformances";
```

and in the package.json file, I have set the

> "proxy": "http://localhost:12914"

But it gives error

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/Etaperformances 500 (Internal Server Error)

Why it gives incorrect port

(3000 is the port that react is running)

Answer (score 1):

**proxy** only has an effect in development, in production we can't use (proxy) . for more information check [Proxying API Requests](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

Comment: I'm not using nodejs. When I'm not using proxy it gives a cors error